# MapReduce Python - too many values to unpack

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to combine the two mappers into one in this tutorial - https://www.knowbigdata.com/blog/multiplying-matrix-using-mapreduce. Given an text file input that has:

`1 1 6 L`

`1 2 5 L`

`1 5 8 L`

`2 3 9 R` ..

where L and R indicates if it is from the left or right matrix. Here is my code:

```
n = 3; 
l = 3;

for line in sys.stdin:
     if 'L' in line:
       (i, k, v) = re.split("[ \t]+", line.strip());
     for j in range(1, l + 1):
           print("%s %s %d\t%s L" % (i, k, j, v));
else:
    (k, j, v) = re.split("[ \t]+", line.strip());
for i in range(1, n + 1): 
           print("%d %s %s\t%s R" % (i, k, j, v));
```

I get this error: `Value error: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

I am new to Python and MapReduce. How do I correct this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the re.split function will return a list of 4 values for your input. You are trying to unpack those 4 values and to assign them to 3 variables.

```
>>> line = "1 1 6 L\n"
>>> re.split("[ \t]+", line.strip())
['1', '1', '6', 'L']
```

If you want to discard the last value, it is common practice to use an underscore as a palceholder variable in Python:

```
i, j, k, _ = re.split("[ \t]+", line.strip())
```